# How to close a dialog box programmatically in Win32

Tags: c, winapi

I have a Window that opens a dialog box (call it DLG_A). From this dialog box, I use the following code to create a modeless dialog box based on a template:

```
 hSchemaWnd = CreateDialog(hInst, MAKEINTRESOURCE(IDD_SHOW_SCHEMA), NULL, (DLGPROC)ShowSchemaCallback);
```

I want to close all opened dialog boxes when I close the main dialog box (DLG_A), so I first tried the `FindWindow()` function, but that does not work with dialog boxes, so I started to store the HWND of each dialog box in an array and from the IDCANCEL of the main application I called this code:

```
SendMessage(dlgHWND, WM_COMMAND, SC_CLOSE, 0);
```

But still, nothing happens, and as far as I can see the callback function for the dialog box does not receive the call.

Any idea what I am doing wrong?

ANSWER:

As iinspectable said in the comment section to destroy this type of window one can use the [DestroyWindow](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winuser/nf-winuser-destroywindow?f1url=https%3A%2F%2Fmsdn.microsoft.com%2Fquery%2Fdev15.query%3FappId%3DDev15IDEF1%26l%3DEN-US%26k%3Dk(WINUSER%2FDestroyWindow)%3Bk(DestroyWindow)%3Bk(SolutionItemsProject)%3Bk(DevLang-C%2B%2B)%3Bk(TargetOS-Windows)%26rd%3Dtrue) command.

Comment: If you close the main window, the dialog boxes will naturally go away when the process terminates

Comment: That doesn't happen, they just stand there look at me. It's so annoying.

Comment: Sounds like there is a problem with how you close the main window then. Please show the window procedure (for the main window) and message loop for your app.

Comment: `SC_CLOSE` is used with [WM_SYSCOMMAND](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/menurc/wm-syscommand), not `WM_COMMAND`. But really, you should fix the real issue instead of trying to work around it. Creating unowned dialogs certainly isn't very common.

Comment: @IInspectable  what do you mean by unowned dialogs?

Comment: "programatically"?

Comment: Unowned: you passed `NULL` as the third parameter to CreateDialog, ergo they have no owner. If you don't know what owner is, read the docs.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan, I have never found that to be a problem. The dialog window is always owned by the current process.

Comment: @PaulOgilvie I'm using the term **owner** in its precise technical form (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/winmsg/window-features#owned-windows), which has a specific meaning in the context of window hierarchies. This dialog has no owner.

Comment: @david-heffernan you are correct. I needed to read the documents :-) and add the owner.

Comment: Please will you provide the missing code that I requested in an earlier comment.

Comment: The main window itself is also a dialog box, so there is a window that opens the main dialog box and that opens the mentioned dialog box. I think I need to explain these thing in the question.

Comment: [CreateDialog](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winuser/nf-winuser-createdialogw): *"The application destroys the dialog box by using the [DestroyWindow](https://learn.microsoft.com/windows/desktop/api/winuser/nf-winuser-destroywindow) function."*

Comment: Please write your solution as answer and mark it as answered. This helps people in the future.